Обязателен ли clang для сборки qt creator?
Всем привет! Обязателен ли компилятор "Clang" для сборки Qt Creator из исходного кода на linux?

Судя по тому, что они просят clangd и libclang (а не только clang), он им нужен в том числе как движок intellisense для. Не уверен, нужен ли им сам компилятор, учитывая что при вызове cmake они не предлагают выставлять CMAKE_{C,CXX}_COMPILER. Почему бы просто не поставить пакеты, которые они предлагают?
